# Predictive model for continuous variable with nonlinear relationship

Tags: python, linear-regression, non-linear-regression

I want to predict valuation using verbal SAS but there exists a strong nonlinearity between the two variables which makes unfit to use linear regression.[below is the scatter plot of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG7iz.png)

Can anyone suggest which model will be good fit for this data or how should I handle nonlinearity so that I can use linear regression.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, they seem pretty unrelated.  It's not just a nonlinear relationship, knowing the value along the x axis gives you almost no information about the y value.

Comment: Any other model that can be used to predict the dependent variable?